# how to tell server that client already finished the output without shutting down the outputstream

Tags: sockets, streaming, outputstream

I having the following code to create a client socket to send/receive data:

```
val socket:Socket = new Socket(InetAddress.getByName("127.0.0.1"), 7777)
val inputStream = socket.getInputStream()
val bufferSource = new BufferedSource(inputStream)
val out = new PrintStream(socket.getOutputStream())

var data = "Hello Everyone"
out.println(data)
out.flush()
***socket.shutdownOutput()***
val in = bufferSource.getLines()
if (in.hasNext) {
  println(in.next())
}
```

If I don't run **socket.shutdownOutput()**, I won't get the data from server,
because Server side is still waiting the input. Therefore I have to shutdown the outputStream.
But if shutdown the output, it can not be reopen. So I have to create a new socket for sending new data.
That caused sending one record needs to create a new socket. This is really awkward.
Is there any other way to tell the server that the output already finished without shutting down the output please.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the server doesn't know when to stop reading and process and reply.

What you need here is an **application-level protocol** that would dictate how server and clients are to communicate - what is a command, how a response to be formatted, etc.

This could be a *line-oriented* protocol - each new line represents a message (in general the message delimiter could be any other character sequence not appearing in the messages).
Or it could be *fixed length* messages; or messages *pre-pended with message length (or type)* to let the other side know how much data yo expect.

Comment: Thanks Nikolai, I also thought of this. I do need to customize the server side logic by myself.